# How to exec bash shell function

Tags: bash, shell, go

We have a large collection of shell functions for various uses that are added to our .bash_profiles and we use on a daily basis.   We call the functions like regular binaries.

I am trying to call these same shell functions from inside a Go app but it cannot find them as it's obviously running in a different context and can't find these in my $PATH.

The error is: 
`exec: "finderx": executable file not found in $PATH`

Does anyone know how to execute shell commands from a Go app in the same context as the terminal it's running in? or maybe to re-source them some how   I don't want to have to re-implement these functions if possible.
I'd like to just call them as we do from scripts to ease the transition period.   We will be gradually moving everything across to Go, but for now, we have to live with the shell functions

Comment: If it's a shell function, it's not an executable. You can only call shell functions from within that shell.

Comment: Understand that. but if the application is running from within that shell, is there no way to see these functions?  This is merely a CLI tool to replace the shells functions eventually

Comment: `bash -c` ? ......

Comment: Still no good, gives an `exit status 127`

Comment: @Cheyne I just checked my solution by invoking a shell alias, defined as a function - everything works as expected :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you can simply invoke `bash -l -c 'your alias function'`. 
Just make sure that your `.bash_aliases` or another dotfile with your functions is sourced from `.bashrc`(which, by the way, should be sourced from `.bash_profile`, as non-interactive login shell doesn't read `.bashrc`).

Answer (score 2):

Create a wrapper script that can run command line arguments.
Example:

**/home/user/run.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
source ~/.bash_profile
$1
```

**test.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)  

func main(){
    testCmd := exec.Command("/home/user/run.sh","func123")        
    testOut, err := testCmd.Output()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } 
    fmt.Println(string(testOut))
}
```